# Script to identify Process Name , Memory , Account Owner in Windows server

Tags: windows, powershell, wmi, win32-process

I am running a web service in Windows machine , and i wanted to know the Memory used by each user while accessing this Web service. 
In Task Manager I could see the ProcessName, UserName, Memory.
Is there a way to get the same by running powershell or batch script?

Please help.

Comment: Question is very unclear. I made a script that lists every process with owner on a computer(that you could run ex. serverside). But when I read it again, it seems you want to know how much memory each user-session uses on the web-server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's may be a cleaner way to do this, but here's an example:

```
$users = @{}
$process = Get-Process

Get-WmiObject Win32_SessionProcess | ForEach-Object {

    $userid = (($_.Antecedent -split “=”)[-1] -replace '"'  -replace “}”,“”).Trim()
    if($users.ContainsKey($userid))
    {
        #Get username from cache
        $username = $users[$userid]
    } 
    else 
    {
        $username = (Get-WmiObject -Query "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_LogonSession.LogonId='$userid'} WHERE ResultClass=Win32_UserAccount").Name
        #Cache username
        $users[$userid] = $username
    }

    $procid = (($_.Dependent -split “=”)[-1] -replace '"'  -replace “}”,“”).Trim()
    $proc =  $process | Where-Object { $_.Id -eq $procid }

    New-Object psobject -Property @{
        UserName = $username
        ProcessName = $proc.Name
        "WorkingSet(MB)" = $proc.WorkingSet / 1MB
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
UserName ProcessName       WorkingSet(MB)
-------- -----------       --------------
Frode    taskhostex                  61,5
Frode    explorer            172,33203125
Frode    RuntimeBroker            21,9375
Frode    HsMgr                   5,578125
Frode    HsMgr64                 5,453125
Frode    SetPoint                 17,4375
```

The code needs to run as admin to get sessions for other users(not just the current user).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried get-process?

You can run that and filter by various factors. You can use -name or -id to filter by process name or PID. ex:

```
get-process -name iexplore
get-process -Id 0     # this returns the idle process.
```

Or, you can filter by other factors

Get processes using more than 1MB of memory

```
get-process |Where-object {$_.WorkingSet64 -gt 1048576}
```

More info on get-process here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176855.aspx